# Sweet Alert confirm dialog disappears before response?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have a problem with Sweet Aler confirm dialog. When I click the delete icon, the Sweet Alert dialog shows for less then a second and then disappears and delete the element. With other words I don't have the chance to click "Delete" or "Cancel". How to stop this dialog to let me choose an option?

```
<a href="insert.php?delete=20"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x pull-right trashbin"></i></a>
---
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('i.trashbin').onclick = function(event){

        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false

        },

        function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm){
            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
        } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
        }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `event.preventDefault();` after:

```
document.querySelector('i.trashbin').onclick = function(event) {
```

Comment: Now it stops the action with event.preventDefault(); but after confirmation it doesn't delete the element... :/

Answer (score 1):

You must replace the 'src' value from the 'a' tag with '#' and pass the 'delete=20' to the function. Then in that function if user clicks 'yes', redirect to the page specified with parameter that you passed to it. This solved my problem. I hope helps you too.

** **Edited** **

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x pull-right trashbin"></i></a>
    ---
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('i.trashbin').onclick = function () {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }).then(function () {
        swal({timer: 1000, title: "Deleted!", type: "success"});
        setTimeout(function goAndDel() {
            window.location.assign("insert.php?delete=20");
        }, 1000);
    });
}
    </script>
```